# Browse to local file and load into webviewer

Tags: java, android, webview

I am trying to push a button in my app to allow me to browse to any local file by launching the default file manager of Android device and then load the file I select into my webview. I know it can be done as I first did it in App Inventor for Android and am now trying to learn the same thing in Eclipse.

I've got this code so far within my onCreate that brings up the default file manager (a selection of 4 programs) and then I browse and select file but it does not load into my app webview, it just closes the browse dialog box.

```
LoadFileButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent LFintent = new Intent();
        LFintent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        LFintent.setType("file/*");
        startActivity(LFintent);
    }
});
```

I know about the assets folder but that is not what I am aiming for; I want a browse and return type thing. I know that I need to webView.loadUrl(something???); later but what? I can't believe that no one has clicked a button in their app to browse to a file on their device and load it into webView...it seems like such a basic thing... and yet I can't find an example anywhere ...

Comment: Do you want to browse a directory and display selected items into your webview?

Comment: any one item that I then subsequently click on (mostly files loadable by a basic default browser I am not worried about pdfs and special file types , mostly just html and text files ...

Answer (score 0):

Use startActivityForResult instead of startActivity.  Then implement onActivityResult and that function will be called when a result is available.

Comment: i've tried that but could not figure out how to implement the parameters/arguments ... it doesn't work ... if you can get it to work show me the code if you can, many thanks, also the exact placement of the onActivityResult ....